# rails cancan access is denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have combined custom authentication with CanCan and to my frustration it is not exactly working as expected. So, here is the snippet of code in my controller

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :profile
    delegate   :email, to: :user
    validates_presence_of :user_id
end

class Api::V1::ProfileController < Api::V1::UserActivityController

    load_and_authorize_resource :user
    load_and_authorize_resource :profile, :through => :user, :class => "Profile"

    def index
       @profile = subject_user.profile
       authorize! :index, @profile
    end
end
```

Here is the `Ability` class

```
class Ability
   include CanCan::Ability

   def initialize(user)

       alias_action :index, :show, :to => :read 

       can :read, Profile
    end
end
```

If I try `can :read, :all` it works fine but with `can :read, Profile` it fails. I had the initial hypothesis that maybe the delagate in the `Profile` class causes the denial but that is not the case. any thoughts?

The page is supposed to render into JSON using rabl

```
object @profile

attributes :first_name, :last_name, :gender
```

-- **Update** --

I figured that namespacing and nesting causes the issues with my code. My controlled is in fact namespaced (I updated the controller code) and I am trying to access `Profile` throught he following routing:

```
namespace :user
    namespace :profile
end
```

I tried the following code for `load_and_authorize_resource` in `ProfileController` (also updated the controller code above) but it is not working. Any thoughts on how it should be modified? Does anything need to be changed in the `Ability` class?

```
load_and_authorize_resource :user
load_and_authorize_resource :profile, :through => :user, :class => "Profile"
```

Comment: can we see the error?

Comment: yeah it is the typical access denied error `#<CanCan::AccessDenied: You are not authorized to access this page.>
Unauthorized user access`

Comment: try @profile, and use the load and authorize in your controller https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions | Or you just simply need to restart your Server.

Comment: `load_and_authorize_resource` bypasses the authentication mechanism. Could it be that my `before_filter` for authentication gets executed after CanCan's authorization?